# How does the Universal Mapping Property encode “no-junk” and “no-noise” in a free monoid?

Tags: category-theory, definition, monoid, universal-property

I am going trough the “Category Theory” book by Steve Awodey.

In the “[**1.7 Free categories**](https://books.google.ru/books?id=zLs8BAAAQBAJ&lpg=PP1&pg=PA18#v=onepage&q&f=false)” chapter the author introduces the following algebraic definition of **free monoid**:

> A monoid $M$ is freely generated by a subset $A$ of $M$, if the following conditions hold:
>
> 1. (**no-junk**) Every element $m \in M$ can be written as a product of elements of $A$ $$m = a_1 \cdot_M a_2 \dotsm a_n \,, \quad a_i\in A \,.$$
> 2. (**no-noise**) No “nontrivial” relations hold in $M$, that is, if $a_1 \dotsm a_j = a'_1 \dotsm a'_k$, then this is required by the axioms for monoids.

Then the author introduces the notion of *Universal Mapping Property* (UMP) as a way to encode the conditions above in terms of category theory:

> Let $M(A)$ be a monoid on a set $A$. There is a function $i \colon A \rightarrow |M(A)|$ (where $|M(A)|$ is the underlying set of the monoid $M(A)$), and given any monoid $N$ and any function $f \colon A \rightarrow |N|$ (where $|N|$ is the underlying set of the monoid $N$), there is a *unique* monoid homomorphism $\bar{f} \colon M(A) \rightarrow N$ such that $|\bar{f}| \circ i = f$ where $|\bar{f}| \colon |M(A)| \rightarrow |N|$.

The author then says that

1. the existence part of the *UMP* captures the vague notion of “**no-noise**” (because any equation that holds between algebraic combinations of the generators must also hold anywhere they can be mapped to, then thus everywhere);
2. the uniqueness part makes precise the “**no-junk**” idea (because any extra elements non-combined from the generators would be free to be mapped to different values).

None of the conclusion above seem to be clear to me, could anyone please explain it?

Comment: I would probably just ignore it, if you’re able to understand the universal mapping property itself. I’m not sure how good an intuitive explanation these properties are.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Monoid homomorphism $\bar f$ preserves structure so, in particular, if there are any equalities between products in one monoid $M$, like $a \cdot_M b = c \cdot_M b$, they are automatically transported to the other one, $N$: $\bar f(a) \cdot_N \bar f(b) = \bar f(c) \cdot_N \bar f(b)$. Some equalities, like the unit and associativity laws are satisfied in any monoid. But suppose that there is an additional equality (the "noise"), for instance $2 \cdot 6 = 4 \cdot 3$ in the monoid of natural numbers $(\mathbb{N}, \cdot)$. Such an equality restricts the type of monoids to which $(\mathbb{N}, \cdot)$ can be mapped. They all have to satisfy this additional equality. So the existence of a monoid homomorphism from the free monoid to *any* monoid with the same generators means that the former has no noise equalities.

Junk is defined as any element that is not generated from the generator set $A$. Let's say, you add $i$ to $\mathbb N$. You can now pick the target monoid to have even more junk, say $j$ and $k$. You can map $i$ to $j$, or you can map $i$ to $k$. Two different mappings that still satisfy the commuting conditions (which you have omitted in your post).

Comment: About junk: there is the commuting triangle in $Sets$: $|\bar f| \circ i = f,  i: A \rightarrow |M(A)|, |\bar f|: |M(A)| \rightarrow |N|, f: A \rightarrow |N|$. If there is junk in $|M(A)|$ I can define multiple $|\bar f|$ (by mapping the junk to different elements in $|N|$) that hold the commuting condition, and hence produce multiple monoid homomorphisms $f: M(A) \rightarrow N$, is that the idea?

Comment: That's the general idea

Answer (score 6):

This is actually not only about intuition, there are formal statements behind that here.

For the first conclusion : let $p,q$ be two expressions written in the language of monoids with free variables $\mathbf x_1,...,\mathbf x_n$, and suppose there are distinct $a_1,...,a_n \in A$ such that $p(a_1,...,a_n) = q(a_1,...,a_n)$.

Then given any $n$-tuple $b_1,...,b_n$ in any monoid $N$, you can map $a_i\mapsto b_i$, $A\to |N|$ (and extend it however you want it on the rest of $A$), so if you are guaranteed the existence part of the UMP, you get a monoid morphism $f:M(A)\to N$ that sends $a_i\mapsto b_i$.

In particular a monoid morphism preserves expressions written in the language of monoids, so that $p(b_1,...,b_n) = p(f(a_1),...,f(a_n)) = f(p(a_1,...,a_n)) = f(q(a_1,...,a_n))=q(f(a_1),...,f(a_n))  = q(b_1,...,b_n)$.

So for any tuple $(b_1,...,b_n)$ in any monoid, $p(b_1,...,b_n) =q(b_1,...,b_n)$.  This means that this equation $p=q$ is imposed by the monoid axioms (if you see "imposed" as a semantic notion, then there is nothing more to say; if you want a syntactic notion of entailment, then you have to use the completeness theorem to conclude here)

For the second conclusion : It is not quite true that the uniqueness property alone implies the "no-junk" thing. However, if you assume existence, then uniqueness then implies that there is "no junk".

Indeed let $N$ be the submonoid of $M(A)$ consisting of all the things that can be written as (possibly empty) products of elements of $A$. Then there is a map $A\to |N|$ which, by existence, extends to $M(A) \to N$, and sends $a\mapsto a$. Therefore, if you compose this with the inclusion $N\to M(A)$, you get a map $M(A)\to M(A)$ such that $a\mapsto a$. Now we use  uniqueness to conclude that this map must be the identity, so that $N\to M(A)$ must be surjective.

But it's an inclusion, in other words $N=M(A)$, so there is "no junk".

To see why uniqueness without existence is not enough to guarantee that there is no junk, you can think of the inclusion $\mathbb{N\to |Z|}$, where you see $\mathbb Z$ as the usual additive monoid.

Then clearly any map $\mathbb Z\to M$ for any monoid $M$ is entirely determined by where it sends $\mathbb N$ (in fact $1$ : it must send it to some invertible element $m$ and then $n$ is sent to $m^n$). Therefore we do have uniqueness, however we don't have existence in general, and there *is* junk ($-1$ can't be written as a sum of nonnegative integers)

So the intuition for 2. should be that, although uniqueness on its own is not what brings the "no-junk" property, it is the part of the UMP that guarantees it when you also have existence.

Comment: "No junk" makes good sense, but I think "no noise" isn't that convincing a way to communicate "no unnecessary relations." Of course, the precise explanation you gave of why there are no unnecessary relations is a great thing to understand.

Comment: @KevinCarlson : I agree that the specific expression "no noise" isn't super convincing (you'll notice that I didn't even repeat it, contrary to "no junk"). I usually say "no relations" (with the understanding that I mean "nothing extra from what has to be there")

Comment: Maybe instead of "no noise", something like "no crushing" or "no folding"?

Answer (score 2):

I will try to rephrase a bit these properties for you, but it is going to be a bit difficult because these sentence capture already pretty well the ideas behind these properties.

So let me start with the "no-junk", because it is in my opinion the easiest to see. When you have a morphism of monoids $f : M \to N$, the only thing it has to satisfy is that it respects the product $f(mn) = f(m)f(n)$. So now the uniqueness in the UMP says that any two morphisms of monoids $f,g : M(A) \to N$ that coincide on each elements on $A$ have to be equal, or in other words a morphism $f : M(A) \to N$ is completely determined by its values on elements of $A$. Until now this is just rephrasing, but think of it this way : assuming that we know all the values of $f$ on the elements of $A$, what are the other values that are determined by the condition that $f$ is a morphism of monoids. With a bit of playing around (that is up to you to convince yourself), you can see that the values that are determined are the products of the form $a_1,\ldots,a_n$, where $a_i$ are elements of $A$. Saying that these product have to determine entirely $f$ hence means that all elements have to be products of this forms. This is the "no-junk" condition.

Now for the "no-noise" part, you can see it like this : the existence in the UMP stated that to determine $f$ you just have to specify its values on elements on $A$, but you are free to do so in any shape or way you want. Suppose that there is an equation of the form $a_1\ldots a_j = a'_1\ldots a'_k$, then since a morphism has to respect the product, the value of $f$ on $A$ would be constraint by the fact that we need to have $f(a_1)\ldots f(a_j) = f(a'_1)\ldots f(a'_k)$, which would not make your choice completely free. Hence the existence in the UMP implies that there is no such relation, which is exactly the "no-noise" part

EDIT : It turns out that Max replied before me, my reply gives you the intuition, whereas his makes it formal, but they are essentially the same

Comment: "**> ... which would not make your choice completely free**"

I feel like you are using the commuting triangle here, but I don't fully understand how, am I right? Could you please elaborate on it?

Comment: Maybe I was a little sloppy in my formulation there. The "commuting triangle" expresses that a morphism $\bar{f} : M(A) \to N$ takes the same value as a given function $f : A \to N$. We already know that a morphism is determined by its values on elements of $A$, and trying to answer the converse : "How free am I to pick a value to associate to each elements of $A$, such that I can extend this into a morphism?" You have to pick values that satisfy the relations satisfied by elements of $A$ in $M(A)$. When they don't satisfy any relation (no noise), you are free to pick anything you want