# I don't understand what "no noise" means

Tags: category-theory

In Awodey's Category Theory, he gives the following definition of a freely generated monoid

> A monoid $M$ is *freely generated* by a subset $A$ of $M$, if the following conditions hold:
>
> 1. Every element $m \in M$ can be written as a product of elements of $A$:
>
> $$m = a_1 \cdot _M \cdots \cdot_M a_n, \quad a_i \in A$$
>
> 2. No "nontrivial" relations hold in $M$, that is, if $a_1 \dots a_j = a_1' \dots a_k'$, then this is required by the axioms of monoids.

Condition number 2 makes *no* sense. What is required? What are $a_1', \dots, a_k'$?

Comment: "free" usually means left adjoint to a forgetful functor

Comment: Left/right adjoints are not introduced until page 209, and I'm on page 24, so it must be using a different definition than that.

Comment: Do you know about free groups? What about free modules? Basis for a vector space? This is the analogous idea but for monoids. #2 is analogous to "linearly independent" for a vector space basis.

Comment: I don't know about free groups or modules, but I do know about bases for vector spaces. I can see how linearly independent can be seen as having "no noise" or having the property of having no "nontrivial relations", but I don't quite see how that could be extended to a monoid.

Comment: In the equation you ask about, it means that $j = k$ and each $a_i = a'_i$.

Comment: If I were to try to extend the idea to monoids I'd say something more like, 'if we have $a_1, \dots, a_n \in A$, and $a_k = a_1 \cdots a_k \cdots a_n$, then $a_1 = \cdots, a_{k-1} = a_{k+1} = \cdots = a_n = \epsilon$, where $\epsilon$ is the identity.'

Comment: @ZhenLin That makes sense. Ugh, what a terrible way to explain this. Awodey could have just said $j=k$ and $a_i = a_i'$, but instead he decides to keep things as vague as possible.

Comment: You can multiply some elements $a$ and some elements $a'$ and get the same result. Freeness means that this happens only by virtue of monoid axioms. E.g. you have $a \cdot (b \cdot c) = (a \cdot b) \cdot c$ but no relations like $a \cdot a = 1$ which don't follow from the fact that it's a monoid.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does Universal Mapping Property encode "no-junk" and "no-noise" in free monoid?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3519790/how-does-universal-mapping-property-encode-no-junk-and-no-noise-in-free-mono)